# customizing jquery mobile theme

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, themes

I began to build jquery mobile based app and started to customize its theme with http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/
but there is just not enough options for me to customize it, so I am asking is there some tool to customize it further?

however http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/# has more options but am not sure can I use it, beacuse its jquery and not jquery mobile

Comment: yes. css that will be generated is awesome tool for more detailed customization. :)

Comment: yes to what? sorry but havent answered my question. not posting this as an answer because there maybe is better solution. the best way I figured its to generate css with themeroller and than customize it manualy

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to customize? Like give a couple examples